# How to write Assert condition to check a particular element is not displayed for dummy users?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assertion

```
By.xpath("//button[@id='Edit']")
```

- This particular Edit button should be displayed for Admin users
- If we login with a different user, we are not showing them the Edit Button
- How to write Assert condition to verify Edit button is not displayed for other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will search for all elements with this XPath and put them in List:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//button[@id='Edit']"));
```

Then I will check if the count (size) of the elements in the list is zero, this will mean that the element was not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='Edit']"))
Assert.assertEquals(true, elem.isDisplayed());
```

Could just check if it's displayed.  Then use Assert.assertNotEquals for the other or just use False.

Comment: Hi Arundeep, Thank u for reply. If element is not displayed it will through error. In my case that is a scenario. I need to verify that Edit button is not displayed for other user. How can i write?

Comment: You can use a count like kb suggest  with Assert.assertEquals(0, elements.size() ));